# Using basic Spider class with scrapy crawl command - can parse() output more than once?

Tags: python, scrapy

I run the following spider:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import PythonlibrariesItem

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "libraries_python_pypi"
    #allowed_domains = ["web"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&show=all&c=308'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
            item = PythonlibrariesItem()
            item['title'] = response.xpath('//table[@class="list"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()').extract();
            item['full_url'] = response.url
            # data_item'] = response.xpath().extract();
            item['description_short'] = response.xpath('//table[@class="list"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()').extract();
            item['repository_link'] = response.xpath('//table[@class="list"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/@href').extract();
            return item
```

The command:
$ scrapy crawl libraries_python_pypi -o output.csv

Most of item's variables/fields contain a list not a single item.

It works well. Only problem is when "item", the result of "parse", is output to the csv file, there is only one line in the csv file, and all the data is compressed into one row.

I roughly know why this is so. Because parse() is only run once, and the ouput is treated as one row.
How do I make it such that every item in the lists extracted is output to a different row in my output csv file?

Answer (score 1):

You must iterate over all TRs to scrape data.

Also do not use `TBODY` tag in your selectors because that tag is is actually not in source-code but added by modern browsers.

You can read this in scrapy documentation: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/firefox.html

> Firefox, in particular, is known for adding `<tbody>` elements to
>   tables. Scrapy, on the other hand, does not modify the original page
>   HTML, so you won’t be able to extract any data if you use `<tbody>` in
>   your XPath expressions.

But if the below code does not work, replace `//table[@class="list"]/tr` to `//table[@class="list"]/tbody/tr`

```
def parse(self, response):
        item = PythonlibrariesItem()

        for TR in response.xpath('//table[@class="list"]/tr').extract():

            item['title'] = TR.xpath('/td[1]/text()').extract();
            item['full_url'] = response.url
            item['description_short'] = TR.xpath('/td[2]/text()').extract();
            item['repository_link'] = TR.xpath('/td[1]/a/@href').extract();
            return item
```

Comment: the code did not work for me. the csv file is blank, with no error on the console. Tried all possibilities, including or excluding tbody. Output on console: … 2017-04-17 20:20:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&show=all&c=308> (referer: None)
2017-04-17 20:20:42 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&show=all&c=308>
{}